# SQL WHERE from html input

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-maps

I'm trying to build a store locator using this tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

The example included in the tutorial only explains how to select stores based on location and radius/distance. I want to add a third criteria (business type) which the user can select from an html form. I'm new to SQL queries - how do I go about modifying the below code to filter by selected business type in addition to the radius/distance?

```
<select id="business" name="business">
    <option value="Grocery">Grocery</option>
    <option value="Pizza">Pizza</option>
    <option value="Coffee">Coffee</option>
</select>
```

---

```
<?php  
$username="#######";
$password="#######";
$database="#######";

// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];


// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("Competitors");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ("localhost", $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysqli_error());
}

// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

// Search the rows in the Competitors table
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, industry,
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM Competitors
HAVING distance < '%s'
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("industry", $row['industry']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

---

```
function searchLocationsNear(center) {
     clearLocations();

     var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
     var business = document.getElementById('business').value;
     var searchUrl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius + '&industry=' + business;
     downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
       var xml = parseXml(data);
       var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
       var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
       for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
         var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
         var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
        var industry = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("business");
         var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

         createOption(name, distance, i);
         createMarker(latlng, name, address, industry);
         bounds.extend(latlng);
       }
       map.fitBounds(bounds);

       locationSelect.onchange = function() {
         var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
         google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
       };
      });
    }
```

Comment: You can setup a column called (for example) "business_type". Then simply add an extra criteria using a `WHERE` clause. I.e.: `WHERE business_type='$business'` --- `$business` would come from a POST variable `$business=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['business']);` such as your present `<select>` --- You may need to replace `POST` with `GET` depending on how your form is setup.

Comment: Sidenote: This `die("Not connected : " . mysqli_error())` working in conjunction with `$connection=mysql_connect...` --- since 99% of your code contains deprecated `mysql_*` functions, you will need to change that to `die("Not connected : " . mysql_error())` --- You will not see the errors, should any happen to appear.

Comment: Thanks for the help/advice! I made those changes but it looks like now my xml output is blank. I have a column in my table called industry which is where I'm store my business type information. This is what I have now:

`$business=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['business']);`

`WHERE industry = '$business'`

Comment: You're welcome. The `WHERE industry = '$business'` will go somewhere inside your query. For example: `... HAVING distance < '%s' WHERE industry = '$business' ...` and the `$business...` goes under `$radius = $_GET["radius"];`

Comment: Hmm, yeah I have it in the query but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Do you have any entries in your `industry` column?

Comment: Plus, you may need to add something like `$newnode->setAttribute("business", $row['industry']);`

Comment: Each of your associated columns already containing entries (*which I assume there are entries*), should contain `Grocery` or `Pizza` or `Coffee` in the `industry` column.

Comment: Added the function that utilizes the business type selection - could the error be in there?
Again, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Read my new comment just above and the other one asking if you already have data in your `industry` column.

Comment: Yeah, the industry column has data (limited to just those three business types)

Comment: It's really hard for me to help you any further. TBH, I never got into Google mapping scripts. Play around with it for a bit, I'm sure you'll get it. Plus, try to move the `WHERE` clause after `FROM Competitors` instead of where I suggested earlier. Sometimes the placement is an issue.